# Javascript Conflict (mootools, jquery_notification)

Tags: javascript

```
<link href="css/jquery_notification.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_v_1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_notification_v.1.js"></script>


<link rel=stylesheet href="css/mootime.css" type="text/css" media=screen> 
<script src="js/mootools1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/mootime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Only one of the following javascript is working.... Please tell me a solution

Comment: Which is working.. please don't leave us to guess, and at least give us the errors you're getting in your console.

Comment: Only one of the following script is working.....that is my problem.

Comment: 2nd one is working. script for time picker.

Comment: if the script for time picker is written first, then the other script will work(script for notification)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`$.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which allows you to use jQuery with other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`jQueury.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

More docs [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)